# How to get images in gallery on android phone?

Tags: android, android-gallery, mediastore

I want to get images in phone gallery and show on gridview.
I use Cursor:

```
final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";
Cursor imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
            null, orderBy);
```

My phone doesn't have SD card, I got `Unfortunately app has stopped` error.
When I replace `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` with `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, nothing happened no errors, no images displayed.

Comment: If your app is crashing you gotta show the stacktrace here. `no images displayed` which part of code do you expect to display images?

Comment: I debuged on my phone, and it said permission deny although I already added android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the Manifest. So, I google it and found out the problem is target sdk. I set it to 22 instead of 24. And now everything ok. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get images by initiating this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
```

then handle it in `onActivityResult()`

```
     @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
}
}

private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

let me know if it help you

Comment: Everything works now, please see my comment above. Thank you and sorry for taking your time.

Comment: yeah on sdk 24, you have to add runtime permissions as well on actual usage of feature, take a look here:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
please accept answer it its helpful for you